# JPA criteriabuilder "IN" predicate on foreign key error: Object comparisons can only use the equal() or notEqual() operators

Tags: jpa, criteria, predicate

I want to select a list of file references from a table by looking at which users have the rights to retrieve that file. To do this I have 3 tables, a file table, an access control table, and a users table.

I am using JPA and Criteriabuilder (because there are more tables involved and I need dynamicle create the query, I am leaving out the other tables and predicates from this question for the sake of readability).

The following code works

```
CriteriaBuilder queryBuilder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();                         
CriteriaQuery<File> queryDefinition = queryBuilder.createQuery(File.class);   
Root<File> FileRoot = queryDefinition.from(File.class);                      
List<Predicate> predicateList = new ArrayList<Predicate>();    

Predicate userPredicate = FileRoot .join("FileAccesControlCollection").join("userId").get("usersId").in(loggedInUser.getUsersId());

predicateList.add(userPredicate );               

queryDefinition.where(predicateArray).distinct(true);                      
Query q = em.createQuery(queryDefinition);
List<Files> results = (List<Files>) q.getResultList();
```

For the userpredicate I want to leave out the last join to the users table because the ID that I want to filter on is already present in the FileAccesControlCollection table, and a join is a computational expensive database operation.

What I tried is to do this:

```
Predicate userPredicate = FileRoot .join("FileAccesControlCollection").get("usersId").in(loggedInUser.getUsersId());
```

But I guess because the userId value in the FileAccesControlCollection entity class is a foreignkey reference to the Users class I get the following error:

```
Exception Description: Object comparisons can only use the equal() or notEqual() operators.  Other comparisons must be done through query keys or direct attribute level comparisons.
```

Is there a way, using the loggedInUser entity or its Id, to filter the files by just joining the File class to the FileAccesControlCollection class and filtering on the userId foreign key? I am kind of new to JPA and using google lead me to a lot of pages but not a clear answer for something which seems to me should be possible.

Answer (score 2):

So "userId" is mapped as a OneToOne? Then you could do,

```
get("userId").get("id").in(...)
```

You could also add a QueryKey in EclipseLink using a DescriptorCustomizer for the foreign key field and then use it in the query,

```
get("userFk").in(...)
```

Comment: No there is a Many to One relationship from the access control to userId. I don't know how to add a QueryKey in EclipseLink using a DescriptorCustomizer. I don't want to do a lot of manual editing of my entity classes.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Predicate userPredicate = FileRoot.join(FileAccesControlCollection.class).join(Users.class).get("{id field name in class Users}").in(loggedInUser.getUsersId());
```

good luck.